# I have a problem with 'with' keyword in Javascript when i run the program it showing undefined value what's the reason?

Tags: javascript, with-statement

```
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
        function Car(amount,color){
            with(this){
                Carprice = amount
                CarColour = color
                
            }

        }
        var Nissan = new Car(10000,"red")
        document.write(Nissan.Carprice)
        document.write(Nissan.CarColour)

        
    </script>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I have created a constructor function with parameter amount and color but I'm getting an undefined value when i run this code i want the parameters to be printed

Comment: FYI, `with` [is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with).  I'd suggest just using `this` directly or create a `class` instead of using function classes which are dated in practice now.

Comment: I think the [description of `with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with#description) is a pretty good explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using deprecated features, use `class`:

```html
<script type = "text/javascript">
  class Car {
    constructor(amount, color) {
      this.Carprice = amount;
      this.CarColour = color;
    }
  }

  let Nissan = new Car(10000, "red");
  document.write(Nissan.Carprice);
  document.write(Nissan.CarColour);
</script>
```